# C# project properties mistakes

Tags: c#

I've played with c# project properties, since this even I've reset the parameters I get those messages in warning window. Is this important for the compiled program ? How can I rectify this ? Because before playing with project properties i was not getting those warnings.

> Warning
>   The referenced assembly "MySql.Data.Entity, Version=6.1.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d, processorArchitecture=MSIL" has a dependency on "System.Data.Entity, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" which is not listed as part of the "Client" TargetFrameworkSubset. If this dependent reference is required, you may get compilation errors.
>
> Warning
>   Reference 'System.Data.SqlServerCe' does not allow partially trusted callers.
>
> Warning
>   Reference 'MySql.Data.Entity' does not allow partially trusted callers.

Comment: are you doing a web application?

Comment: Restore your project from source control.  If you don't have any then you've learned a valuable lesson today ;)

Comment: If fact my program is working with no problem only there is still first warning in the warning window. I build my program and it worked on another computer without problem except I have to put "MySql.Data.dll" in same folder of my exe program. But I want still resolve this problem. Because there must be a step back. I have only changed some parameters in project if I replace this values with old values it must be corrected!!

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to your project's properties.
2. Go to the Application tab
3. From the "Target Framework" dropdown list, select ".Net Framework 3.5" instead of ".Net Framework 3.5 Client Profile".

(Use 4 instead of 3.5 if you're using 4, but from the error it looks like you're using 3.5)

Comment: Among the Target Framework I have only .Net Framwork 3.5 client profile does not exist. I've changed security tab also but I've reseted this. Because when I've put in security tab "enable clickOnce security setting and changed to "this is a partial trust application" and changed the "sqlclientpermission" to include. I can even not log to server. So the calamity that I've created must be somewhere there.

Comment: @IsmailGunes Can you diff your changes in your source control?

Comment: As I told above I've no ".Net Framework 3.5 client profile" I have only ".Net 3.5 Framework" so I get the same first warning message. The last two messages I know where they come from. I explaned above. But the first message is still existant.

Answer (score 0):

In VS Project Properties window -> Target framework (it shouldn't point to the "Client Profile" distribution of .NET)

Answer (score 0):

Ismail Never change a running system lol.
I'm wonderuning why you does not have stored your work on repository.

If you have the default standalone application than you have to check the following:

Select:

- Publisch tab and then select "The application is available offline as well....".
- Security tab "Enable clickOnce security settings" must be not hecked!
- Signing tab "Sign the ClickOne mainfests" must be not checked!
- Services tab "Enable client applicaiton service" must be not checked!

**REBUILD**

If you have ASP application or you have some code security or your application need permissions than you have to determine the Permissions for a ClickOnce Application.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/91z17fc9(v=vs.80).aspx

I have this will solve your problem.

Comment: As I'am a beginner of C# I was discovering the project properties tab. As you must know without doing that you can't learn. I was thinking there is always  a solution for stepping back for this kind of changes. As I d'ont remember what I've changed I begin to change as you told. Your solutions did not work thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I've found the answer of the debility I've did. It's shown in the picture. I've checked the JIT option. Because, when I have used the exe program in another computer as I' did not take a copy of "MySql.Data.dll" my program was not working and was finishing  by an exception. In the warning of this exception it was saying about to check the JIT. I've checked it(and I forgot it). After trying all the possiblity I found the solution. But I don't understand why this dll is protected. It must be a part of GNU ??

[image: reason of the problem]
<sub>(source: [turcguide.com](http://turcguide.com/stack/mysqldll.jpg))</sub>

Comment: Finally my problem continued after the changement JIT a while after.  Then after a long search in SO topics (I'am sorry I forgot) Ive found that someone has installed "mysql-connector-net-6.7.4" and that's resolved his problem. I've did the same and my problem is finished.(I was using 6.1.6)